# An empty space shows after translationY animation

Tags: android, android-animation, android-toolbar

I am hiding the `Toolbar` when scrolled down, the only views left would be the `SlidingTabLayout` and the `ViewPager`, just like the behaviour that PlayStore has. But I can see a white empty space after the `SlidingTabLayout` is moved.  How do I eliminate this and let the `ViewPager` occupies that extra space?

When scrolled up, `Toolbar` shows
[image: When scrolled up, Toolbar shows]

When scrolled down, it leaves empty space from `SlidingTabLayout`
[image: When scrolled down, it leaves empty space from SlidingTabLayout]

```
@Override
public void onScrollUp() {
    if (isToolbarHidden()) showToolbar();
}

@Override
public void onScrollDown() {
    if (isToolbarShown()) hideToolbar();
}

private void showToolbar() {
    moveToolbar(0);
    moveTabs(0);
}

private void hideToolbar() {
    moveToolbar(-mToolbar.getHeight());
    moveTabs(-mTabs.getHeight());
}

private void moveTabs(float toTranslationY) {
    if (ViewHelper.getTranslationY(mTabs) == toTranslationY) return;

    ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(ViewHelper
            .getTranslationY(mTabs), toTranslationY)
            .setDuration(ANIMATE_TIME_MILLIS);

    animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
            float translationY = (float) animation.getAnimatedValue();
            ViewHelper.setTranslationY(mTabs, translationY);
        }
    });
    animator.start();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried calling ViewPager.requestLayout() when the animation updates?

Comment: yes i have tried, it doesn't work

Comment: Hi, have you been able to solve this issue?

Comment: @jaibatrik here try this http://mzgreen.github.io/2015/02/28/How-to-hideshow-Toolbar-when-list-is-scrolling(part2)/

Comment: Hi! have you find the answer of this issue?

Answer (score 0):

set the linear layout where you place your extended toolbar to android:animateLayoutChanges="true"

Other than that you want to set that space the toolbar occupies to GONE somehow in order to kick the animation without flickering, and get the blank space out of the way. I never worked with extended Toolbars but this is what I did with a normal toolbar when I wanted it out of the view completely.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **RelativeLayout** instead of **LinearLayout** to contain your toolbar.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This answer is too small. You can either post this as comment to quesiton